# UI not updating when called on main thread Swift

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading

I am having a hard time getting my annotation's subtitle to update, I am calling it on the main thread and ensuring that the result is correct.

Can anyone see why it would not be updating?

```
 let stopAnnotation: UUStopAnnotation = view.annotation as! UUStopAnnotation

        // Else get the stop estimation
        webService?.getStopEstimation(routeId: stopAnnotation.routeId, stopId: stopAnnotation.stopId, completion: { (result) in

            print(result)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                stopAnnotation.subtitle = result
            })

        })
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't change an annotation in the map. Remove this annotation and replace it with one that has the same coordinates but the new subtitle.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed it by adding this:

```
    webService?.getStopEstimation(routeId: stopAnnotation.routeId, stopId: stopAnnotation.stopId, completion: { (result) in

        print(result)
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            mapView.removeAnnotation(view.annotation!)
            stopAnnotation.subtitle = result
            mapView.addAnnotation(stopAnnotation)
            mapView.selectAnnotation(stopAnnotation, animated: true)
        })

    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried forcing the map view to redraw itself?

```
view.setNeedsDisplay()
```